# How to insert a value in Retrofit?

Tags: javascript, java, android, list, api

I'm trying to make a PATCH request to my retrofit API.

When I make a patch request, the API is expecting this structure of values.

```
[
{
    "propName":"username","value":"bruno70"

},
{
    "propName":"email","value":"bruno@bruno.pt"
}
]
```

So, in Android studio, I have two models:

UpdateUser, which receives the various propNames and values that I require:

```
public class UpdateUser {

 List<UpdateUserzinho> userzinhos;

public void setUserzinhos(List<UpdateUserzinho> userzinhos) {
    this.userzinhos = userzinhos;
}
```

}

Then, I have the model which contains the set of propnames and values:

```
public class UpdateUserzinho {

private String propName;
private String value;

public String getPropName() {
    return propName;
}

public void setPropName(String propName) {
    this.propName = propName;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

So, we insert all the propnames and values into the UpdateUser model which gets patched into the user model, which looks like this:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("_id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

@SerializedName("email")
private String email;

@SerializedName("contact")
private String contact;

@SerializedName("zipcode")
private String zipcode;

@SerializedName("userImage")
private String userImage;

@SerializedName("password")
private String password;

@SerializedName("is_admin")
private String isadmin;

public User(String id, String username, String email, String contact, String zipcode, String userImage, String password, String isadmin) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    this.userImage = userImage;
    this.password = password;
    this.isadmin = isadmin;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getUserImage() {
    return userImage;
}

public void setUserImage(String userImage) {
    this.userImage = userImage;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getIsadmin() {
    return isadmin;
}

public void setIsadmin(String isadmin) {
    this.isadmin = isadmin;
}
}
```

The problem is that while I can successfully put the values together by doing (hardcoded just for the example):

```
  UpdateUser updateUser = new UpdateUser();
            List<UpdateUserzinho> updateUserzinhoList = new ArrayList<>();
            String propName1 = "username";
            String username = "bruno70";
            String email = "email";

            UpdateUserzinho updateUsername = new UpdateUserzinho();
            updateUsername.setPropName(propName1);
            updateUsername.setValue(username);

            UpdateUserzinho updateemail = new UpdateUserzinho();
            updateemail.setPropName("email");
            updateemail.setValue("bruno@bruno.com");
            updateUserzinhoList.add(updateUsername);
            updateUserzinhoList.add(updateemail);
            updateUser.setUserzinhos(updateUserzinhoList);
```

Then I make the call to the server to the updateUser model, which all works fine, however, the output is the following:

```
{"userzinhos":[{"propName":"username","value":"bruno70"},{"propName":"email","value":"bruno@bruno.com"}]}
```

So, the API doesn't accept the values because it has the "{"userzinhos": " at the beginning and the "}" at the end. I must get rid of those in order for my API to accept the values.

I tried converting it to String and sending a string converted to JSON but android automatically stringifies it by placing "\" in between the spacings, which leads to the API not detecting the values.

I've also thought of having a nameless List (if it is possible) - So, if "userzinhos" wasn't named anything, it wouldn't technically add the values i've mentioned before.

Also, the API code which gets the PATCH request looks like this:

```
   exports.edit_user = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.userId;
  const updateOps = {};

  for (const ops of req.body) {
    updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
  }

  User.update({ _id: id }, { $set: updateOps })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "User updated"
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

This is for a school project.

Comment: set `List<UpdateUserzinho>` as body of request instead of `UpdateUser` in your retrofit interface

Comment: That's what updateuser is or isn't it? UpdateUser is basically a list of Updateuserzinho

Comment: both are different as when you have an object, JSON starts with `{` but with list/array, it starts with `[` which is something you want.

Comment: Exactly.. It was "the same thing" except it wasn't. A few changed to the code lets me update it now. Thanks you!

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `UpdateUser` you must use `List< UpdateUserzinho>` to send to server.

Comment: Please check this edit, I had made an incorrect refrence earlier. Basically the server accepts an array/List of objects, though what you are sending is an object with a key "userzinhos" which has the required list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I was doing the same, which, in theory I was, but the server was not accepting it